# Something wrong with my m3u8 bandwidth value

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

I use ffmpeg to encode my sample videos following the recommanded bitrates in Technical Note TN2224, then use HLS tools to segment it and create playlists, finally create the variant plist file "all.m3u8"
     I used the validation tool to validate my HLS content, it ended up showing except for the 64k audio only bandwidth is low, others are stay in the same bandwidth, I opened "all.m3u8" using text editor and seeing that all other bitrate contents are using the same bandwidth. No matter how I change parameters in the ffmpeg command, I still can't correct them. The following command is the one I used to encode contents:
`ffmpeg -i input.m4v -acodec libfaac -vcodec libx264 -s 480x360 -b 350k -r 29.97 -vpre medium output.mp4`

The following command is for generating the segments and plists:
`mediafilesegmenter -b http://www.example.com/stream/ -I -f ~/Documents/sample/ output.mp4`

The following command is for generating the all.m3u8:
`variantplaylistcreator -o all.m3u8 http://www.example.com/stream/110/prog_index.m3u8 ~/Documents/sample/110/prog_index.m3u8 -iframe-url http://www.freeyourteam.com/stream/110/iframe_index.m3u8 http://www.example.com/stream/200/prog_index.m3u8 ~/Documents/sample/200/prog_index.m3u8 -iframe-url http://www.freeyourteam.com/stream/200/iframe_index.m3u8 http://www.example.com/stream/350/prog_index.m3u8 ~/Documents/sample/350/prog_index.m3u8 -iframe-url http://www.freeyourteam.com/stream/350/iframe_index.m3u8 http://www.example.com/stream/550/prog_index.m3u8 ~/Documents/sample/550/prog_index.m3u8 -iframe-url http://www.freeyourteam.com/stream/550/iframe_index.m3u8 http://www.example.com/stream/64/prog_index.m3u8 ~/Documents/sample/64/prog_index.m3u8`


and in my "all.m3u8", the bandwidths are all 523894:

Please allow me to ask two more basic questions:
In the tech note, recommanded bitrates are 64 Kbps, 110 Kbps, 200 Kbps, 350 Kbps, 550 Kbps, I wonder if this value includes the audio bitrate or exclude the audio.
How do you insert keyframe to segment? Because in the document it says:"You must include at least one keyframe per segment, preferably more. If you only include one, put it at the beginning of the segment." I don't quite get how you can do it.
Thank you very much for your help and I do appreciate your time.

Comment: Give all your actual command rather than just some abstract version of it. Who is creating the all.m3u8?

Answer (score 1):

Jason,
  To create all.m3u8 should it not be given multiple m3u8 files each corresponding to a different bitrate?

I am guessing you run ffmpeg say 4 times to create for 4 bitrate files. Then you run the segmenter 4 times to create 4 set of segments and its individual m3u8 files.

Finally you have to tell the variantplaylistcreator where the location of the various m3u8 files per bitrate to create a single master m3u8 file.
Eg.

```
variantplaylistcreator -o mymedia_all.m3u8 http://mywebserver/mymedia_lo/prog_index.m3u8 mymedia_lo.plist http://mywebserver/mymedia_med/prog_index.m3u8 mymedia_med.plist http://mywebserver/mymedia_hi/prog_index.m3u8 mymedia_hi.plist
```

I don't see you providing the various filese seperately. I hope you get the picture.

EDIT: To answer your other questions:
Bitrates include audio. What you need to do is ensure you have a fixed key frame interval in your encoding. This will allow the segmenter to segment the files at regular intervals. you don't insert anything anywhere.

Out of curiosity why not directly use ffmpeg to give you the output segmented files? It supports it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, that's exactly what I did. I didn't list them all because they are simply the same except for the bit rate.

Comment: @Jason, your variantplaylistcreator command has only one m3u8 being given to it, no? Should it not have 4 m3u8 files being given to it? Am i seeing something wrong?

Comment: Well in that case I suggest you simply edit the all.m3u8 manually. It is simple enough. I have also edited my answer for some of the other questions you had.  The thing i don't understand is what is -iframe-url doing?

Comment: -iframe-url is used to identify the iframe index file which will be used for fast forward/rewind. I think edit the file manually isn't the right option in my situation. I have maybe over 50 videos to convert, I simply use python to write an script to handle all the works. So I have to figure out the correct setting for ffmpeg to get the best result.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for everybody's attention and suggestions. I finally figured it out. The reason why the bandwidth stayed the same for different bitrate is that my ffmpeg command missed couple settings. I ended up using the following command:
`ffmpeg -i inputVideo.m4v -f mpegts -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 64k -vcodec libx264 -b 350k -s 480x360 -r 29.97 -flags +loop -cmp +chroma -partitions +parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -subq 5 -trellis 1 -refs 1 -coder 0 -me_range 16 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -bt 200k -maxrate 350k -bufsize 350k -rc_eq 'blurCplx^(1-qComp)' -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -level 30 -aspect 4:3 -g 30 -async 2 output.ts`

I put it here so that other people who have the same problem as me will have a reference.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have uncovered a bug in variantplaylistcreator. I recommend to verify that the sub-streams really are the bitrate you expect, and if it's really putting the wrong value, to report it to apple.

It might have something to do with using multiple -iframe-url. I can't understand why it would be necessary to specify it more than once. Adaptive streaming won't work if the substreams have different I-frame positions -- at least all of the segment boundaries must be aligned.

If you need to fix the playlist up programmatically, I recommend to use ffprobe (from ffmpeg suite) to extract the bitrate of each substream, and replace the bandwidth number with the extracted value.

Comment: Please see my answer, I found out that it was my ffmpeg command's problem.

Comment: iframe-url will be different for different bitrate segments. Thanks for you help.